# How many times can strictly convex functions intersect?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

Some time ago, I saw a post related to the number of times that two convex (and continuous) functions' graphs can meet. In general, infinitely many times: one can think, for instance, of $g(x):=x^{2}$ and $f(x)=x^{2}+\sin(x)$.

But, if $f,g:[0,+\infty)\longrightarrow [0,+\infty)$ are continuous, strictly convex and 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=+\infty
$$
then, at least intuitively, one can state that $f$ and $g$ meet in, at most, two points, that is, the equation $f(x)-g(x)=0$ has, at most, two solutions. What do you think?

Comment: Are we talking about functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$? In higher dimensions convex functions can meet at infinitely many points. Also, for functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which are continuous and convex may have infinitely many meeting points... take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2$ for $|x|\leq 1$ and $g(x) = 3x$ for $x\geq 1$, $g(x) = -3x$ for $x\leq -1$.

Comment: The functions are defined in $[0,+\infty)$.  However, your example is valid: f(x)-g(x) has, at most, two zeros in $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Are you assuming that the functions meet transversely (or the equivalent for functions that aren't at least $C^1$)?

Comment: The $f$ and $g$ you already have are almost there. Just have $f$ switch to a much faster increasing function when $x>n\pi$, for some large $n$. This way the limit if the ratio is infinite, and $f$ and $g$ can still meet as many times as you like.

Answer (score 3):

Following up from my comment, here is a counterexample where both $f$ and $g$ are convex, continuous, have the desired property $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x) = +\infty$, but their graphs share infinitely many common points:

$\hskip2in$ [image: counterexample]

You require that the functions are *strictly* convex and are defined on $[0, +\infty)$, but it is not difficult to modify the above counterexample; take
$$g(x) = x^2,\text{ for} x\geq 0$$
and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x), \text{ for } x \in [0,1],\\
x^4, \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Both functions are continuous, strictly convex, their values are nonnegative, and
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^4}{x^2} = \infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks!! You are right. However, I think in the functions $f(x):=1+k_{1}^{x}+\ldots + n^{n}$ and $g(x):=k'_{1}+\ldots + k'_{n}^{m}$, where the integers k and k' are distinct and m<n. Thus, it is possible that the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ has more than two solutions? I think not: in other case, f must be decreasesing in some interval, which is not possible.