# How many times can strictly convex functions intersect on a bounded interval?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  be two strictly convex function on an open interval $(a,b)$. Assume $f$ and $g$ are not identical.    Can we find an upper bound on how many times these two functions can intersect on $(a,b)$?

We can assume that both functions are analytic on $(a,b)$. This assumption makes the problem non-trivial.

There is a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847918/how-many-times-can-strictly-convex-functions-intersect), but it is about $\mathbb{R}$ and not $(a,b)$.

**Edit:** Furthermore, can an assumption that one of the function is strictly increasing help?

Comment: You’re talking about intersections of the graphs?

Comment: Isn't the answer still infinity?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No. If the functions are analytic then the number of intersections must be finite.

Comment: @Boby: Are you sure? Can you prove it? (And if so, why did you ask the question?)

Comment: @TonyK  Let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Note  that $h(x)$ is also analytic.  Analytic functions can have only finitely many zeros on a bounded interval. This follows from identity theorem and Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. The reason I asked this question is that this argument does not provide a bound on the number of the intersection but only a statement of finiteness.

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass doesn't apply to open intervals.

Comment: I'm sticking my neck out here, but I reckon $\sin(1/x)$ is real analytic on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @TonyK  Yes, this is a counterexample. Thank you.  I have to change my question to a closed interval. I guess I will do this some other time.

Answer (score 1):

An uncountably infinite number of times.

Consider the interval $[-1,1]$.  Let $f(x)=x^2$.

And let
$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{eqnarray} x^2 & \text{ if } x < 0 \\ 2x^2 & \text{ otherwise }\end{eqnarray}\right..$$

These functions intersect an uncountably infinite number of times on the interval $[-1,0]$.

Comment: But that function is not analytic.

Comment: @TonyK Does it say that the functions should be analytic?

Comment: Yes it does.${}$

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the example given in the answer in the related question to some interval $(a,b)$ that intersects $(-1,1)$ but is not contained in it. For any other $(a,b)$, just rescale and shift (which doesn't break analycity).

However, adding the condition of analycity does, indeed, change the answer (assuming that you're requiring $f$ and $g$ to not be the same function: as analytic continuations  are unique, if $f = g$ on some subinterval $(c,d)$, then $f = g$ everywhere (cf [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function#Analytic_varieties_and_unique_continuation)). Thus, this counterexample can't work. Further, it's not hard to see that this is the only way that we can have uncountably many points of intersection.

[NOTE: It's very possible there's something wrong at the end of the following paragraph. I'd be much obliged if someone who knows more than me about real analytic functions could check it and let me know how to fix it: I'm keeping this here because the rest of the answer is correct, and I've got a pretty strong impression that there *is* some way to fix this bit]

You also can't have countably infinitely many points where $f$ and $g$ coincide in a bounded interval $(a,b)$: if you do, then there's some convergent sequence $(a_n)\to c$ of such point (as any enumeration of the points gives a bounded sequence, which has a convergent subsequence). Either every such $(a_n)$ is eventually constant, or not. In the former case, there must be some $\delta > 0$ such that for all points $x\neq y$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f(y) = g(y)$, we have $|x - y| > \delta$, but there can't be infinitely many such points in a bounded interval, a contradiction. Thus, we have some convergent subsequence that is not eventually constant, hence $\{x \in (a,b) | f(x) = g(x)\}$ has some accumulation points. [NOTE: This is where I went wrong in my initial attempt at writing this]. I feel like there's now a way to conclude that $f = g$, but I'm not sure how exactly.

You can still have any finite number that you like, though: take $f(x) = x^2 + \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x^2 - \sin(x)$. Then both $f$ and $g$ are analytic and convex, but $f(x) = g(x)$ whenever $x = n\pi$ for any integer $n$. Thus, $(0,(n+1)\pi)$ contains $n$ points at which $f = g$, and this can be mapped by something that doesn't break convexity or analyticy to any $(a,b)$.

Comment: $(a_n)$ doesn't necessarily have any accumulation point in $(a,b)$. For instance, $a_n=a+1/n$. (Also, what if it did?)

Comment: @TonyK We can extend real analytic functions to larger domains uniquely, so the first issue doesn't matter: simply extend $f$ and $g$ to a slightly larger domain and proceed: the resulting function is still convex on $[a,b]$, which I feel like should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I was wondering if more assumptions about the first derivative can help. For example, if one of the function is increasing.

Comment: No, we can't extend real analytic functions to larger domains. For instance, $\tan$ is real analytic on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.